# Mesh using Eigen: MatrixX3f or std::vector<Vector3f>?

Tags: c++, graphics, gpu, eigen

I'm using the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library in a computer graphics project with meshes that will change often.

What are the performance implications of using a dynamic Eigen Matrix for all the vertex positions, normals, etc?

Should I use:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> vertices;
```

or

```
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> vertices;
```

I will have to copy the mesh data to GPU after every change, but as I understand it, I can do this with memcpy efficiently with both representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory layout of both representation are exactly the same. The main differences are that a std::vector<> is more flexible if you need to insert vectors or stuff like that. On the other hand a Matrix<.,3,Dynamic> is an Eigen object, so it is easier to perform some operations on it, e.g.:

```
Matrix<.,3,Dynamic> data;
data = Affine3f(...) * data; // apply an affine transformation
data.colwise().norm(); // get the norm of each vectors
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Vector will probably consume more memory, because it usually allocates more space than required to store data and vector will call default constructor and destructor for `Eigen::Vector3f` every time you resize it. AFAIK, default `Eigen::Vector3f` constructor is empty, so it will cost you zero in release build (but you may experience performance problems in debug build, due to this and debug iterators). On the other side, `Eigen::Matrix` will reallocate memory each time you resize it (it will also copy the content just as `std::vector` if you use conservativeResize), this is slow.

Howewer, I still recommend you to use vector, because it is more convenient. You can dynamically add elements, resize it without reallocation, it is simpler to use standart algorithms on vector. If you want to be sure, that your vector don't consume more memory than required, you can use this trick to resize it:

```c++
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> vertices;
vertices.swap( std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>(size, Eigen::Vector3f()) );
```

Or see [shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit)

And yes you can use memcpy to copy data efficently using both representation. But using `std::copy` will do the same job with same performance in release build (sometimes it is even replaced by compiler with `memcpy`).

Howewer, if you are still not satisfied with performance, here are tips I've made for myself to make a decision in such cases:

- If you are going to frequently resize vertices array (add or remove elements) -> go with `std::vector` to avoid frequent reallocations.
- If you store huge chunks of data in vertices array -> go with `Eigen::Matrix` to avoid excessive memory consumption.
- If you are not satisfied with performance in debug mode (this will luckily be true if you frequently process data in your vertices array) -> go with `Eigen::Matrix`, `stl` debug iterators can ruin the performance (only true for MSVC)

Also consider [boost::shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm)(scoped_array), these are especially designed to store large chunks of data without consuming extra memory. Using them makes more sense in your scenario.

Comment: This answer contains good tips; unfortunately I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues in general with arrays of dynamically allocated matrices :

- you won't be able to use a global `memcpy` to copy your whole structure : in the case of dynamically allocated matrices (for example, you have an `std::vector<float*>` instead of an `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f>`), your array only contains a serie of pointers, and all these pointers can point to very different locations in memory. So, performing a `memcpy` will only copy the pointers, not the data, and there is no way to change that since your elements are not consecutive in memory (only their pointers are).  Instead, you would need to go through each element of your `std::vector`, access it with `operator[]` and `memcpy` the element separately. For instance, when doing your `memcpy`, you will have `sizeof(Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 3, Eigen::RowMajor>) = sizeof(void*) + 2*sizeof(int)` (or something similar : it stores a pointer and a number of rows and columns), while `sizeof(Eigen::Vector3f) = 3*sizeof(float)` since it really stores data and not pointers.
- if you need to frequently create and destroy matrices, doing that with dynamically allocated matrices will be much slower. Having fixed-size matrices allows for the allocation to be made on the stack, which makes it much faster.